# Mapping a table function to a model using SQLAlchamy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a CTE which resides in a table function which requires a parameter being passed into it. The data  I need is then called with something like

`SELECT * FROM myThingFunction('e543149c-6589-49c6-b962-bf2503c0e278')`

What I would like to do if possible is map a SQLAlchamy model so that I can apply filters, limits etc to the record set returned, for example

`qry = session.query(Thing).limit(100)`

What I am struggling with is how do I handle the parameter. I know that I am treating the function like a table which feels a bit wrong as the function is more of a composite set of relations rather than a table mapping to just one type of domain object but I need to get this data into Python somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen [the recipe for mapping arbitrary selects](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/mapper_config.html#mapping-a-class-against-arbitrary-selects)? You can write a factory method which returns a class representing the query for a given parameter:

```
def myThingFunction(param):
  tmpSelect = select(..)
  class tmpCls(Base):
    __table__ = tmpSelect
  return tmpCls
```

But there is a note below this recipe which states that creating a mapping is unnecessary. I haven't tried it, but in principle,

```
session.query(func.myThingFunction("bar")).all()
```

might work, too. (`func.foo` creates a `GenericFunction` on the fly, see the documentation for [FunctionElement](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/functions.html?highlight=functionelement#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.FunctionElement) and below.)